# Function declarations in javascript objects cannot be made in advance

Tags: javascript, function, object

```
let obj = {
    fn: () => {
        return 'fn'
    }
}
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.fn)) // undefined
}, 1000) 
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.fn)) // undefined
```

I want to use props.obj.fn() in some vue-components, But It's undefined. I think this problem maybe cause of JavaScript function advance. How can I fix this? Please help me.

Try to use setTimeout but It's not work.

Comment: Did you mean `JSON.stringify(obj.fn())`?  `obj.fn` is a function. You need to _call_ that function if you want to see the string `'fn'` that it returns

Comment: I suppose it's also worth saying that you can't `JSON.stringify` a _function_ because JSON doesn't support functions.  But, you _can_ `.toString()` a function, although this is almost certainly **not what you intended** -- but in your case `obj.fn.toString()` would return a string something like `"() => {\n        return 'fn'\n    }"` which is the source code for the function itself. and you _can_ `JSON.stringify` a string.  (I'm confident your original code was just a facepalm / typo.)

Comment: You answer very quick, thanks. My situation maybe little complex. I use webWorker in js, So, I need to deep copy this obj. 
Like below： ` const { arr, userPidsMap } = await workerFn(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(treeRoot)), JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(currentTabData.data)))`
Call currentTabData.data.fn() in webWorker. After read you answer I think maybe I need to change another way to deep copy this obj.